# How to add an object to JSON (nodeJS)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Yes I already know about

```
json.newvalue = 'newvalue'
```

But I'm not looking for that...
I have an empty JSON

```
plugins = {};
```

Now I need to add 5 items to it for example:

```
{"name":"test"}
{"name":"test2"}
```

I am looking for something like this: `plugins.add({"name":"test"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, json is a string representation of an object, what you have in your code is an object. However, it seems that you don't want a JavaScript object, but an array.

```
var plugins = [];
plugins.push({"name":"test"});
plugins.push({"name":"test2"});
```

plugins will now be

```
[
    {"name", "test"},
    {"name", "test2"}
]
```